# ADF Faces: How to customize contextmenu with Javascript and Managedbean?

Tags: javascript, jsf, oracle-adf

I'am looking for a good tutorial to customize my ADF Faces contextmenu.

After spending some times on google i find [Adding close this / close others / close all to the UIShell](http://technology.amis.nl/2012/07/11/adf-11g-adding-close-this-close-others-close-all-to-the-uishell/).

But it's not what exactly i expect.
[image]

An ADF Faces Contextmenu look like the image above if you press mouse right taste on a button or a link. How can i customize my contextmenu to open a link in new tab or windows as usual on a browser like the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quit simple i just need to add the following code to my web.xml to enable the settings

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>oracle.adf.view.rich.ACTION_LINK_BROWSER_CONTEXT_SUPPRESSION</param-name>
    <param-value>no</param-value>
</context-param>
```

At runtime, end users can invoke a browser's context menu by right-clicking on the links rendered by certain components, as described

The components for which you can configure this behavior include the following:

```
af:commandLink

af:commandImageLink

af:commandMenuItem (stand-alone or within an af:menuBar component)

af:commandNavigationItem if no value is specified for the destination attribute, the ADF Faces framework enables the browser context menu in the following scenarios:

For the two anchors that af:commandNavigationItem renders when inside an af:train component

When an af:commandNavigationItem renders inside an af:breadCrumbs component

When an af:commandNavigationItem renders inside an af:navigationPane component (any hint--tabs, bar, buttons, choice, list)

af:panelTabbed: the tabs and overflow indicators

af:panelAccordion: the disclosure link and overflow indicators
```

You cannot configure this behavior for components that specify a destination and do not invoke an action. Examples of these components include the following:

```
af:goLink

af:goImageLink

af:commandNavigationItem
```

where you specify a value for the destination attribute and no value for the action attribute